# Documentation on `avr-as`

Tags: avr, avr-gcc, assembler

I'm starting learn AVR microcontrollers. But my OS is Linux. I have installed `avr-binutils` with `avr-as`. But I can't find documentation on it; especially, avr syntax (for example, for x86 standrd intel and as syntax differ).

Answer (score 3):

The documentation, such as it is, is at http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/

The basic AVR syntax is pretty much the same as you will find in the Atmel datasheets (unlike the way GCC uses a different x86 assembler syntax than some other x86 compilers). You can also use `avr-gcc -S file.c` to see the assembly `gcc` generates for a file.

Comment: A slightly oftopic question: are `avr-gcc` and `avr-as` compatible with C and Assembler compiler from AVR studio?

Comment: And thanks. I found documentation on http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/index.html

Answer (score 1):

The avr assembler commands are always the same: [AVR instruction set](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=avr%20instruction%20set).
Here is a simple workflow.

1. Write your program in a file filename.
2. avr-as filename program.out
3. avr-objcopy -j .text -j .data -O ihex program.out program.hex

The hex file contains the opticodes of the compiled instructions (it is a text file, you can open and look at it). It is to be uploaded to the avr.

1. avrdude -p partname -c programmer program.hex

I'm not sure, you might need to add -mmcu=partname to the assembler command line. Experiment.

Btw congrats for starting out with the assembler. Later on you will move to programming in C, but the experience will be valuable for you.

Another note: check this out [AVR makefile](http://electrons.psychogenic.com/modules/arms/art/8/AVRProjectOrganizationStandardizedAVRMakefileTemplate.php). You can just use it for now, compiling C and assembly projects alike.

Yet another note: I didn't check the fourth (4) instruction I gave you - here I don't have a programmer. It ... could be wrong :D

Good luck and have fun!

Answer (score 0):

How about using [Atmel Studio](http://www.atmel.com/Microsite/atmel_studio6/default.aspx) inside a [virtualbox](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads) machine? Both are free. You also need a Windows (XP/Vista/7) license and installation disk, but maybe you can get one, easily.

Comment: AVR development on Linux with eclipse-avr can be pretty decent.

Comment: there is also http://avra.sourceforge.net/ which is what I use.

Answer (score 0):

I am using two simple AVR assembler under my Ubuntu. They are up to date and open source and work fine.

gavrasm http://www.avr-asm-tutorial.net/gavrasm/index_en.html

avra http://avra.sourceforge.net/